# iOS, How to export app to MFI certification

Tags: ios, xcode, external-accessory, mfi

My app uses ExternalAccessory and communicate with some hardware by bluetooth. This hardware and app will be send to Apple to MFI certification.
How to export app in XCode 6.4? In Product->Archive in window "Select a method for export" I have:

1. Save for iOS App Store Deployment
2. Save for Ad Hoc Deployment
3. Save for Enterprose Deployment

Option 2. is not good because it contain list of devices. Options 3. I think is also not good. So, I generated app using 1. but app not install properly by iTunes on my iPhone.

Comment: You can run your app even without making Archive directly by using Development or Distribution Provisioning Profile.here in this case use 2 option.

Comment: @baydi Could you tell me how to do that? Is any way to export app without build ipa archive?